# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in .dll

Tags: c#, windows

I'm developing a windows application in C#. In my application I've used one static class.

Below is the code:

```
public static class clsNumber
{
     private static object vValue;

     public static object Value
     {
         get
         {
              return Value;
         }
         set
         {
              Value = value;
         }
     }

     public static string HexValue
     {
         get
         {
              try
              {
                   return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Hex(vValue);
              }
              catch
              {
                   return Convert.ToString(vValue);
              }
         }
         set
         {
              Value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val("&H" + value);
         }
     }
}
```

From another class the value of "HexValue" of the above mentioned class is being set. Below is the line of code:

```
iStick = sOutPut.Substring(0, 8);
clsNumber.HexValue = iStick;
```

While executing the above line of code the below mentioned error is coming:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in <.....>.dll"
```

Can anyone please help me with the resolution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Value property getter uses the Value property.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter.  Which uses the Value property getter...  Kaboom!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an non-terminating recursion here:

```
public static object Value  
{
     get
     {
          return Value;
     }
     set
     {
           Value = value;      
     }
 }
```

The line `return Value` in the getter calls the getter recursively and that leads to stack overflow. And similarly for the setter.

I think you meant:

```
public static object Value  
{
     get
     {
          return vValue;
     }
     set
     {
           vValue = value;      
     }
 }
```

i don't see what's to be gained from using an explicitly named field here to back to property. I'd remove `vValue` and declare the property like this:

```
public static object Value { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things :

1. You forgot that you have created vValue field.
2. Don't Make the Property Recursive (unless really needed, and which is resolvable after some iterations). Here you are calling Value property inside Value property.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static string HexValue
```

in above line use StringBuilder instead of string