# Getting System.StackOverflowException with Unity Interceptor in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container, interceptor

I'm setting interceptors from Unity into my WCF project and I get a `System.StackOverflowException` when I call a method from my service. This comes from Interceptors I set up but I don't know how to solve it.

FYI: I check if I had a [circular dependancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561242/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexception-occurred-in-syste) or [a non-terminating recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024072/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexception-occurred-in-dll)

I'm using Unity v4 and Unity.WCF v3.0

Here's the code

the Factory for the web service

```
public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // register all your components with the container here
        List<string> lstNomAssemblyToLoad = new List<string>();
        List<Assembly> lstAssemblyToLoad;

        lstNomAssemblyToLoad.Add("Service");
        lstNomAssemblyToLoad.Add("Interfaces");
        lstNomAssemblyToLoad.Add("Bll");
        lstNomAssemblyToLoad.Add("Dal");

        // Loading specific interface from unity.config
        container = container.LoadConfiguration();

        // Resolving interfaces without explicit declaration
        lstAssemblyToLoad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => lstNomAssemblyToLoad.Contains(a.GetName().Name)).ToList();
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
        container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(lstAssemblyToLoad),
                                WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
                                WithName.Default,
                                WithLifetime.ContainerControlled, 
                                getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[]
                                {
                                    new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                                    new InterceptionBehavior<ExceptionInterceptionBehavior>()
                                }, 
                                overwriteExistingMappings: true);

    }
}
```

My InterceptionBehavior

```
public class ExceptionInterceptionBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public bool WillExecute
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I get `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` every time I'm calling a method of my web service ?

The trace

[image]

If you need more information please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank for the help

---

**UPDATE**

If I remove interceptors, of course I do not have exception anymore:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(lstAssemblyToLoad),
                                WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
                                WithName.Default,
                                WithLifetime.ContainerControlled, 
                                null, 
                                overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```

But If I change just `WithName.Default` to `WithName.TypeName` and keep interceptors, I don't get exception... I don't understand why...

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(lstAssemblyToLoad),
                                WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
                                WithName.TypeName,
                                WithLifetime.ContainerControlled, 
                                getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[]
                                {
                                    new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                                    new InterceptionBehavior<ExceptionInterceptionBehavior>()
                                }, 
                                overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```

Comment: can you share the exception stack trace?

Comment: Updated the answer with a screenshot of what I get

Comment: i don't think that's the complete stack. if you scroll down further, does any of it begin from your code?

Comment: @Dhawalk No it doesn't, It might be circular dependency in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I found a workaround by setting `getName` to `WithName.TypeName` or `t => t.GetType().Name` but now I'm facing a mapping issue :)</strike>

However I still don't know why this is solving the `StackOverflowException`. If anyone knows, I'll give him a cookie.

**EDIT**
With my colleague we reviewed it and found this solution [Registration by convention and interception causes ResolutionFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480123/registration-by-convention-and-interception-causes-resolutionfailedexception/29814283#29814283)

So we add a new Type filter

```
public static class TypeFiltres
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> WithMatchingInterface(this IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        return types.Where(type =>
            type.GetTypeInfo().GetInterface("I" + type.Name) != null);
    }
}
```

and changed the configuration into the WCF Factory like this

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(lstAssemblyToLoad).WithMatchingInterface(),
                                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                                WithName.Default,
                                WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
                                getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[]
                                {
                                    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                                    new InterceptionBehavior<ExceptionInterceptionBehavior>()
                                });
```